# Can firebase handle one billion active users?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have an idea of an application that will be revolutionary and everyone that has iOS or Android will use it
so my question is can Firebase handle for example one billion active users reading and writing every day and how much will be the pricing?

Comment: Maybe. However, you have provided no details on resource consumption. For example, adding 2+2 requires one set of resources. Calculating the effect of gravity requires a different set of resources. Until you specify what resources are required, how do you expect a realistic answer? Google would not approve the billing account budget required to support that many users unless you are a major company. Also, consider that Google charges per user. One billion users would cost $2.5 million per month. Then there are the costs for all the other resources.

Comment: Assuming each user consumed 100 KB of network bandwidth per day at $0.12 per GB, your monthly networking costs would exceed $360,000 per month. Assuming each user stored 10 MB of data, your storage costs would exceed $230,000 per month. I have only touched on the beginning of the costs for one billion users. Based on the limited information in your post, I will guestimate that Firebase will cost you north of $5 million per month for one billion users. That does not include discounts that Google might offer for long-term contracts.

Comment: I really like this comment Mr @JohnHanley The answer is yes I actually did my calculations and it will reach in a certain point one billion users and the app itself will let the users profit from it and when they withdraw their money I will take a fee like Upwork doing and with that fee i will pay the billing of the firebase the app is like a game and everyone will really really profit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can Firebase handle for example one billion active users reading and writing every day?

The short answer is yes, it can. However, according to the official documentation, there are some limitations that you should be aware of. In the case of Firestore, here are the [limits and quotas](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).

> How much will be the pricing?

Here are the details regarding [billing](https://how%20much%20will%20be%20the%20pricing%20?), and here are also some [billing examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example). If you want, you can also [simulate the pricing](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) using concrete numbers.

When it comes to billions of users, keep in my to always [monitor the usage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage).